# How to make an rxjs marble sync grouping only take up one frame

Tags: rxjs, marble, jasmine-marbles

According to https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/testing/marble-testing.md#marble-syntax

```
'--(abc)-|': on frame 20, emit a, b, and c, then on frame 80 complete
```

So how do I represent "on frame 20, emit a, b, and c, then on frame 40 complete.

Ie how can I stop the sync group itself taking up frames?

Comment: You can't; there's nothing you can do about it. The example from the documentation that you've included in the question describes the `TestScheduler`'s behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

[cartant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6680611/cartant) has answered this question in his comment.

There's no way to do it - sync groups will always take up extra frames even though all members occur in the frame of the opening bracket.

Comment: Just in case this might help anyone else, there's an alternative library that provides this functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50530591/853678