# How to test observables which emit grouped events with rxjs marbles?

Tags: rxjs, marble, jasmine-marbles

According to [rxjs marbles documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/marble-testing.md#marble-syntax) the current behaviour for the sync groupings is the following:

```
'(ab)-(cd)': on frame 0, emits a and b then on frame 50, emits c and d
```

From the docs:

> While it can be unintuitive at first, after all the values have synchronously emitted time will progress a number of frames equal to the number of ASCII characters in the group, including the parentheses

Ok, but how do I test an observable like this (using marbles or any other technique):

```
const observable$ = of(1, 2).concat(of(3, 4).delay(20));
```

Are there any workarounds?

*There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839094/how-to-make-an-rxjs-marble-sync-grouping-only-take-up-one-frame) on Stack Overflow but there is no answer on 'How to actually work around it and test this kind of observable'.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my project I migrated to [rx-sanbox](https://github.com/kwonoj/rx-sandbox) where sync grouping works correct and it solved my problem.

So, in rx-sandbox this is correct:

`'(ab)-(cd)': on frame 0, emits a and b then on frame 20, emits c and d`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what version of RxJS you're using because you're mixing prototypical and pipable operators but it looks like RxJS 5.5.

In RxJS 5.X it's a bit clumsy. You could rewrite your test like this:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing/TestScheduler';
import { assert } from 'chai';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/concat';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';

const scheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
  console.log(actual, expected);
  return assert.deepEqual(actual, expected);
});

const observable$ = of('a', 'b').concat(of('c', 'd').delay(50, scheduler));

scheduler
  .expectObservable(observable$)
  .toBe('(ab)-(cd|)');

scheduler.flush();
```

See live demo (open console): https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-marble-test?file=index.ts

You know this test passes because it doesn't throw any error. Try changing any of the delays or values of `next` emissions and it'll throw an error.

Also have a look at this answer: [How do I test a function that returns an observable using timed intervals in rxjs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732988/how-do-i-test-a-function-that-returns-an-observable-using-timed-intervals-in-rxj/42734681#42734681)

However, I'd strongly recommend upgrading to RxJS 6 because it makes everything much easier with `cold` and `hot` "creation" functions where you could just use `const observable$ = cold('(ab)-(cd|)')` to create the same sequence as you're doing with `of(...).concat(...)`.

Testing in RxJS 6:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/marble-testing.md
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/internal-marble-tests.md

Comment: Well, if you want to use marble tests you'll have to at least pass the `scheduler` to `delay`. Otherwise it's not able to work with time and marble tests are based proper on timing.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, @martin.
In your answer you assumes that I can edit my original observable. But I'm trying to test some observable from the real code of my application.
`
class SomeService {
observable$ = of(a, b).concat(of(c, d).delay(20));
}
`

I know that this observable suppose to produce the following stream: '(ab)-(cd)'. And I want to test it using marbles. My problem is that using the marble syntax i can't do it because of sync groupings syntax. In Rxjs 6 too. 
For my project I migrated to rx-sanbox where sync grouping works correct and it solved my problem